# Get IP address of all devices on LAN using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I want to get IP address of all devices on LAN using Action Script 3. Can you tell me how can I do this ? Also, If you can, please give me a simple example written in AS3.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do this in just ActionScript 3.  You may be able to write a native extension and call that native extension from an AIR app

Comment: But what is "native extension", that is, what programming language should I use to write such application ? Note that I'm not a network expert...

Comment: You could write such an extension in at least C/C++ but possibly you could write it in Java or .NET languages as well.

Comment: A Native Extension is a way to extend the capabilities of Adobe AIR.  I believe you write them in the language depending on the system.  On Windows and Mac, I believe you would write them in C.  On iOS you would use Objective C. On Android you would write them in Java.  Start here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html and Google "AIR Native Extensions" for more information.  The Native Extension route will only work if the underlying operating system can somehow expose the data you want.

Comment: You really can't do this (particularly in AS3 directly as others stated) unless you have a computer setup as a router or you have a router that will spit you back this information (something that actually established the IP tables for routing).  You can use something like net view in windows to get a list of devices it's aware of on the LAN that use NetBIOS http://www.chicagotech.net/netviewcommand.htm but definitely not a full list without knowing something about your router and how you can communicate with it.

Comment: Or if there was a server on the same network then that server could relay the info back to the clients.

Comment: Can I make a broadcast to all computers on the network in order to requre its IP addresses ?